# Class Availability Check

Tags: java

I have a **dependency jar**, 
For build A, dependency.jar  will contain classes A,B,C,D.
For build B, dependency.jar  will only contain classes A,B,C

Problem:

Source:
my code is making use of all the classes A,B,C,D.

Goal:
The code I have written should remain the same for build A and B.

Problem:
But obviously class D won't be available in Build B. So my code should handle the  availability of class D. At the same time the extra code , I am going to add to handle availability of class D , should not slow down my code.

Please suggest possible solutions.

One Solution:
We will make use of Class.forName() API to check the availability of the Class.

Problem with the solution:
API will throw classdefnotfound every time if it is not available, and as per my understanding class.forName will try to load the class so , will be slow.

NOTE:
Class D is optional, if it is not available , the functionality related to that class should be disabled

Comment: How is your code going to work if it makes use of a class D, which isn't available?

Comment: Whats the use of class D then ??

Comment: class D is optional, if class D is not there, that functionality will be disabled

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method getResource() on class or class loader object of any class. If it's return null then the
class is not present like below

```
URL url=SomeClass.class.getClassLoader().getResource("className.class");
 if(url==null)//class not present
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to dynamically load your Class D using reflection then call its methods, the same way you do it for database drivers. You cannot make direct references to your class in your code else your code wont compile and complain of unavailability of the class. If your class could be loaded at runtime then turn on the required features toherwise turn them off.